# Event Template - can I increase the maximum number of participants value?

Tags: civievent

We run training sessions on behalf of 3rd party organisations who source the attendees.  I'd like to be able to allow them to login and enter the participant details for all of the attendees - up to a max of 25 - is this possible? 

I found an old thread about code-hooks, but I have no idea how to do this.  I was hoping that this would have been a configurable value hidden in a config file or DB somewhere...? 
Thanks, Joe.